# Alinhar a coluna para direita pdfsharp

Tags: c#, pdf

Bom dia, estou utilizando a biblioteca pdfsharp, e estou querendo alinhar pela direita a coluna referente ao valor. Poderiam me ajudar, por gentileza? Segue abaixo o código.

```
            graphics.DrawString(f.ENT_DAELOC, font, PdfSharp.Drawing.XBrushes.Black, new RectangleF(vColuna, vLinha, 100, 0));
            graphics.DrawString(f.ENT_MATRIC, font, PdfSharp.Drawing.XBrushes.Black, new RectangleF(vColuna + 50, vLinha, 100, 0));
            graphics.DrawString(f.ENT_MED_ANO_OUT, font, PdfSharp.Drawing.XBrushes.Black, new RectangleF(vColuna + 130, vLinha, 100, 0));
            graphics.DrawString(f.ENT_RIGEM, font, PdfSharp.Drawing.XBrushes.Black, new RectangleF(vColuna + 190, vLinha, 100, 0));
            graphics.DrawString(f.ENT_VALOR.PadLeft(18, ' '), font, PdfSharp.Drawing.XBrushes.Black, new RectangleF(vColuna + 220, vLinha, 100, 0));
            graphics.DrawString(f.ENT_VR_MEDIDO.PadLeft(18, ' '), font, PdfSharp.Drawing.XBrushes.Black, new RectangleF(vColuna + 320, vLinha, 100, 0));
            graphics.DrawString(f.ENT_VR_DIFERENCA.PadLeft(18, ' '), font, PdfSharp.Drawing.XBrushes.Black, new RectangleF(vColuna + 420, vLinha, 100, 0));
            graphics.DrawString(f.ENT_REMANEJ, font, PdfSharp.Drawing.XBrushes.Black, new RectangleF(vColuna + 520, vLinha, 100, 0));
            graphics.DrawString(f.ENT_DEBAUT, font, PdfSharp.Drawing.XBrushes.Black, new RectangleF(vColuna + 580, vLinha, 100, 0));
            graphics.DrawString(f.ENT_CORTE, font, PdfSharp.Drawing.XBrushes.Black, new RectangleF(vColuna + 640, vLinha, 100, 0));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `DrawString` tem um overload que aceita um `StringFormat`.

ex:

```
var format = new StringFormat
{
    Alignment = StringAlignment.Far,         
};

graphics.DrawString("texto", font, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(vColuna, vLinha, 100, 0), format);
```